# By updating, the data of "Reopen Closed Editor" disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-code

A VS Code contributor told me it wasn't a bug, but I'd like to clarify the cause, so I'll ask.

[that issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181188)

`%AppData%\Code\storage.json` has a history of closed files and windows, but why wasn't VSCode loading it?
For example, the specification changed, it used to be stored in json, but now it is stored in the database?

If `%AppData%\Code\storage.json` were to disappear from now on, it would be a problem...
When the same thing happens this time, you will not be able to salvage the information of the open window...

If anyone is familiar with the "Reopen Closed Editor" or the specification of the `%AppData%\Code\` directory, could you give me some information?

### Information before and after the occurrence

I had this problem when trying to update VS Code.

#### Version before update

sorry...
didn't take notes...

#### Updated version

```
Version: 1.77.3 (user setup)
Commit: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
  Date: 2023-04-12T09:16:02.548Z
Electrons: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Sandboxed: No
```

Comment: I don't even have such a file like `%AppData%\Code\storage.json` on my machine (Ubuntu `>/.config/Code/...`). I _do_ have a `.../Code/User/globalStorage/storage.json`.

Comment: @user
Thanks for the valuable information!

I also had `%AppData%\Code\User\globalStorage\storage.json` in my environment!

And this file seems to record the latest window state.
(`%AppData%\Code\storage.json` is old and not updated)

In the future, when the same thing happens, it seems good to look inside `%AppData%\Code\User\globalStorage\`.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's another file with a similar name that you can take a look at (apparently you had success there):

- Windows: `%AppData%\Code\User\globalStorage\storage.json`
- Ubuntu Snap: `~/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/storage.json`

Otherwise, try browsing the workspace database files `.../Code/User/workspaceStorage/<workspace_hash>/state.vscdb` with a database browsing tool.